# Error while sending email using php

Tags: php

SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. (10013) The following From address failed: info@gmail.com : Called Mail() without being connected

```
    $mail = new PHPMailer();                
    $mail->IsSMTP(); 
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1; 
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true; 
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";  
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
    $mail->Port = 587; 
    $mail->Username = "gmail.com"; 
    $mail->Password = "password";        
    $mail->From = "info@gmail.com";
    $mail->FromName = "name.com";
    $mail->Subject = "Register";
    $mail->MsgHTML($userMsg);


    $mail->AddAddress("email address", "name");
    //$mail->AddAddress($rowUser['user_email'], $rowUser['user_name']);
    $mail->send();
    $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the error message?

Comment: Try using `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';` instead of `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';`

Comment: for ssl its showing the same error

Comment: is anyone came across such error and found any solution

Comment: Does settings should be done in gmail account any idea anyone guys

Comment: Trying enabling the 'Access for less secure apps' Security setting and see if it helps

Comment: it has been already enabled

Answer (score 0):

TLS is correct, you could try SSL, change port to 465. Check your credentials. Is on-screen Username "gmail.com"?

Try this:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(); 
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "yourname@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "yourpassword";
$mail->SetFrom("example@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body =$body;
$mail->AddAddress($email);
if(!$mail->Send())
{
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Just checked, everything forks fine. Make sure that "Allow less secure apps" is ON in your gmail settings